# Split column in two with same condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, case

I have a column named X, in this column are actually stored 2 different information. I know how to split them but I would like something optimized or at least more optimized than my query.

I have a query working but I expect it having difficulties with a large set of data.

```
  SELECT
    CASE SUBSTRING(X,1,3)
      WHEN 'AAA' THEN SUBSTRING(X,1,10)
      WHEN 'BBB' THEN SUBSTRING(X,1,20)
    END as firstinfo,
    CASE SUBSTRING(X,1,3)
      WHEN 'AAA' THEN SUBSTRING(X,11,5)
      WHEN 'BBB' THEN SUBSTRING(X,21,5)
    END as secondinfo
  FROM Table
```

Results are like this :

```
      firstinfo     |secondinfo
------------------------------
AAAfstdata          |smthg
BBBfirstdatalongerXX|else
```

Would it be possible to only have one condition since it's the same `case` and `when` conditions, showing 2 columns

Comment: Store two items of information in two different columns.  That is the optimal approach.

Comment: That is planned, but we have to do with what we have for the time being

Comment: Are you actually having difficulties with large dataset?

Comment: Your new sample data still is invalid. Also you can't have this both ways. You can't both violate 1NF and have uber fast performance. Properly normalizing this would allow to get the performance you need. Until that happens you are stuck jumping though hoops.

Comment: I'm still in the development phase but I've been told to expect a 70Go table,
it might be impossible to have anything better, but as least for my personal knwoledge I would like to know if anything's possible

Comment: There's little to "optimize" here as such; the optimizer will already evaluate the `SUBSTRING(X,1,3)` only once. You could consider `CROSS APPLY` and a table-valued function (and/or embedding these expressions as computed columns so you don't repeat yourself all over the place), but it's probably overkill. String manipulation in T-SQL is clumsy and slow no matter how you slice it (pun intended)

Comment: Good grief....if you are still in development then why do you "have to do with what we have for the time being"? Fix the data structure and you have no need for this question at all.

Comment: Allow me to explain better, we have something in production
And we have to develop a program extracting data using our data set
So as much as I would like to change this, I can't just barge into this "mess" and do whatever I like

Comment: OK you kind of keep going back and forth so we will just assume that you can't fix the problem and have to move forward. Can you post some valid sample data and the expected output? Your code will produce errors with the sample data given because the string values are too short.

Comment: "optimized" in what way? what do you mean by "having difficulties with a large set of data"? Do you have many columns to extract, many rows to select from or both?

Comment: Note that any queries of the form `where firstinfo = '...'` are going to be slow no matter what, because you're working on computed values. For just extracting the data for display purposes, there's not really anything to optimize (or a pressing need to). For effective/efficient use of the columns as separate values, you'd need at least indexed views, but better yet just a new table. To remain compatible with existing code, you can make `X` computed by `CONCAT`ing. (Of course, the same caveats with indexing apply to *that* column then.)

Comment: it should be valid now, the last part (secondinfo) is expected to be shorter
Optimized is a general word and I meant it that way, particularly in time consumption I would say
But it might have been follish of me to think it was an interesting question

Comment: The expression looks deterministic so you can simply create a persisted, computed column and done. You can also create an index on such columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XML trick to split them.

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Table table (X varchar(30));

insert into @Table (X) values
('AAAfstdatasmthg'),
('BBBfirstdatalongerXXelse'),
('ZZZ4567890123456789012345');

SELECT 
X2.value('/x[1]','varchar(30)') as firstinfo,
X2.value('/x[2]','varchar(30)') as secondinfo
FROM @Table
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT 
   CAST('<x>'+STUFF(X, 
         case LEFT(X,3) 
         when 'AAA' then 11 
         when 'BBB' then 21 
         else LEN(X)-4 
         end
         ,0,'</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML) AS X2
) as ca;
```

Or use VALUES

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Table table (X varchar(30));

insert into @Table (X) values
('AAAfstdatasmthg'),
('BBBfirstdatalongerXXelse'),
('ZZZ4567890123456789012345');

SELECT 
LEFT(X, COALESCE(pos, LEN(X)-5)) as firstinfo,
SUBSTRING(X, COALESCE(pos, LEN(X)-4), IIF(pos is not null, LEN(X)-pos+1, 5)) as secondinfo
FROM @Table t
LEFT JOIN (VALUES 
 ('AAA',11),
 ('BBB',21)
) v(code, pos) ON v.code = LEFT(X,3);
```

**Result:**

```
firstinfo               secondinfo
-------------           ----------
AAAfstdata              smthg
BBBfirstdatalongerXX    else
ZZZ45678901234567890    12345
```

But for that example, I guess one could also focus on the length of the secondinfo:

```
SELECT 
LEFT(X,      case LEFT(X,3) when 'BBB' then LEN(X)-4 else LEN(X)-5 end) as firstinfo,
SUBSTRING(X, case LEFT(X,3) when 'BBB' then LEN(X)-3 else LEN(X)-4 end, 5) as secondinfo
FROM @Table;
```

Comment: If for "optimized" we read "less typing", then this might be considered "more optimized". But as to performance, it's probably going to stink. (Disclaimer: not actually tested and compared with repeated `SUBSTRING`s.)

Comment: The CROSS APPLY doesn't select from a table, it's just using the values of the record. So it should be fine (probably).  This is indeed more about a way to define the split position only once.

Answer (score -1):

you can use PIVOT to separate data into columns with its own data. here is how PIVOT works

```
SELECT * FROM table1
PIVOT(
       SUM(Sales) -- for strings use MAX(comment) for example.
       FOR X --this is the column which will be split into parts
       IN (First_Hand, Second_Hand) --this creates 2 columns
) AS PIVOT1
```

SAMPLE
Original data from a table named Drinks

[image]

After I used PIVOT

SELECT * FROM temp.dbo.drinks
PIVOT(
        SUM(avail_amt)
        FOR loc
        IN(CA, DC, FL)
        ) PIV1

Then results

[image]